# TYPEFACE.JS Selecting different fonts

Tags: javascript, fonts, preview, typeface.js

I'm trying to create a font preview form like on dafont.com or a similar website using typeface.js.

I'm having trouble getting typeface.js to render font for anything but a heading tag. Further, how can I choose which font to use from a dropdown?

Thanks SO much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation?

Have you converted your fonts for use with typeface?

From the Typeface website:

**By default typeface.js will render text for heading elements (h1, h2, etc.)** when those elements' styles reference typeface.js fonts.

Remember that heading styles are bold by default, so you'll either need to add font-weight: normal to you heading styles, or load the bold version of the font if that's what you're after.

**Any other HTML element referencing a typeface.js font needs to have typeface-js in its list of class names.** If you have an element that already has a class name, for example, , you can just add another class name by saying .

You'll have to load external stylesheets before loading typeface.js. Otherwise, Firefox 3 might not have applied the styles when typeface.js tries to draw the text.

Unfortunately, specifying the font-stretch property will only work with inline CSS and not from any stylesheet.

In some circumstances in IE7 you may see a couple of milliseconds' delay before the browser shows typeface.js text after the page is rendered, producing a "flicker" effect. One way to get around this is to manually put a call to _typeface_js.initialize() just before your closing  tag.

---

If your looking to dynamicly change the font displayed in a single canvas, you would probably have to read the documentation for typeface.js and see if there is some way to do that, there is also a forum on the typeface website. Otherwise you would have to write something yourself that interacts with the typeface script to change the displayed font.